# value of specific group attributes of product

Tags: magento

in manage attributes set say default i created a group say "my custom group" now i want to get value of all attributes under this group for current product how can i do this?..

```
$attributeValue = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                            ->load($this->getProduct()->getId());
                            echo "<pre>";
                            print_r($attributeValue);
                            echo "</pre>";
```

show all attributes for product

Answer (score 0):

Hello You can not fetch the Attributes values as per group.

Magento Follow the **`EAV Model`**.

So if you want to access the value form any Custom attribute value for that product then you have to follow the Magento Standard Way as below.

**`Syntax`**

> $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($Id);

Once you write above line the it will fetch all data for that product. Now you want to fetch the value of any attributes like name, color or any other attributes then use below code.

> $product->getData('Attribute Code');

Or

> $product->getName();

This way you can access the details of any attributes.

Answer (score 0):

First thing:

```
$_prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
```

There are 2 kinds of attributes:

1. The ones in 'General' where you can use:

   $_prod->getAttributeText('some_attribute_code')
2. The ones in a custom group where you use:

   $_prod->getData('some_attribute_code')

The difference is the function you call *getAttributeText* or *getData*